# FileUpload usings node.js angular restful-apis

Tags: angularjs, node.js, rest, file-upload, multer

I am trying to upload a file to a directory but cannot figure out how to set up using RESTful-API paradigm.

I have the following Client Side code

Client/Testarea.html

```
<input type="file" name="fileUpload" value="fileUpload" placeholder="none" file-model="myFile" />
<br>
<br>
<button ng-click='uploadFile()'>Upload</button>"
```

Client/Testarea.controller.js

```
$scope.uploadFile = function()
        {
       var file = $scope.myFile;
       var uploadUrl = "/multer";
       var fd = new FormData();
       fd.append = ('file', file);

       TestareaSvc.uploadFileSrv(uploadUrl, fd, 
         {
             transformRequest: angular.identity,
             headers: 
             {
                "Content-Type": undefined
             }
         });
        };
```

Directive

```
angular
.module('test')
.directive('fileModel', ['$parse',
  function ($parse)
  {
      return {
              restrict: 'A',
              link: function(scope, element, attrs)
                    {
                     var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
                     var modelSetter = model.assign;

                     element.bind('change', function()
                     {
                      scope.$apply(function()
                      {
                       modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                      });
                     });
                    }
             };
  }]);
```

Client/Testarea.service.js

```
this.uploadFileSrv = function(uploadURL, fd, obj)
    {
     console.log('TestareaSvc - uploadFileSrv');
      function uploadFileSrvSuccess(response)
      {
        console.log('Upload File Success');
        return response;
      }

      function uploadFileSrvFailed(error)
      {
        console.log('Upload File Failed');
        return error;
      }

      var doc = new Object();
      doc.uploadURL = uploadURL;
      doc.fd = fd;
      doc.obj = obj;
      return $http.post('/api/testareas', doc)
       .then(uploadFileSrvSuccess)
       .catch(uploadFileSrvFailed);
    };
```

Server Code

Api/Testarea.controller.js

```
//* Using Rails-like standard naming convention for endpoints.
//* GET     /api/testareas              ->  index
//* POST    /api/testareas              ->  create
//* GET     /api/testareas/:id          ->  show
//* PUT     /api/testareas/:id          ->  update
//* DELETE  /api/testareas/:id          ->  destroy


var multer = require('multer');

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
 destination: function (req, file, cb) {
  cb(null, './uploads/')
 },
  filename: function(req, file, cb) {    
  cb(null, file.originalname + '-' + Date.now() + ".txt")   
  }
 });
var upload = multer({ storage: storage });


// Gets a list of Testareas
exports.index = function(req, res) {
 console.log(‘index’)
};

// Gets a single Testarea from the DB
exports.show = function(req, res) {
console.log('exports.show');
};

// Creates a new Testarea in the DB
exports.create = function(req, res) {
console.log('exports.create');
};

// Updates an existing Testarea in the DB
exports.update = function(req, res) {
console.log('exports.update');
};

 // Deletes a Testarea from the DB
exports.destroy = function(req, res) {
console.log('exports.destroy');
};

function handleError(res, err) {
console.log('handleError');
return res.status(500).send(err);
}
```

The client.testarea.html  displays the webpage information to the user in which the user selects a file from the file managers.  After selecting the file, the user will upload the file to the specified folder (/multer).

The client/testarea.html communicates with the client/testarea.controller.js.  The client.testarea.controller.js contains the directive required to extract the file attributes.  The client/testarea.controller.js communicates with client/testarea.service.js.  Since the folder resides on the webserver.  The client/testarea.service.js will communicate with api/testarea.controller.js.  The api/testarea.controller will upload the file to webserver.

I can communicate the necessary information from the client/testarea.html to the api/testarea.controller.js.  My first question is:  “Am I pass the appropriate information to the various scripts?”  However, the bigger question is I cannot get the figure out get the file to upload.  I get the api/testarea.controller.js and do not know how to ensure I pass the appropriate information to it.

I have looked at numerous examples of file upload using multer but every example using client side coding.  I could not find a single example, which passes control to an API controller.

TIA

Comment: As an addition to this question, can i get an explanation on how I can determine the location of the upload directory. TIA

Answer (score 0):

Well you can counter this problem via two ways.

First - You upload the file in one request and then you get a response back from the server when the file is uploaded with the file name and the respective directory address that'll you'll need to store in the database, I guess.

Second - You can send the file along with other fields from the Angular to your node.js server and then complete the whole process in one go.

Let me know which method you want to use, I'll post code references based upon that.

Okay, as you wanted. Method 1.

I am using ngfileupload module on the frontend for ready made directive, you can replicate this process as you like.

Code Sample (Copied from Official Documentation)

[Link of the Js Fiddle for frontend code](http://jsfiddle.net/danialfarid/0mz6ff9o/135/)

Controller Code

```
var app = angular.module('fileUpload', ['ngFileUpload']);

app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'Upload', '$timeout', function ($scope, Upload, $timeout) {
    $scope.uploadFiles = function(file, errFiles) {
        $scope.f = file;
        $scope.errFile = errFiles && errFiles[0];
        if (file) {
            file.upload = Upload.upload({
                url: 'https://angular-file-upload-cors-srv.appspot.com/upload',
                data: {file: file}
            });

            file.upload.then(function (response) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    file.result = response.data;
                });
            }, function (response) {
                if (response.status > 0)
                    $scope.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
            }, function (evt) {
                file.progress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 * 
                                         evt.loaded / evt.total));
            });
        }   
    }
}]);
```

Server Side Code

The Route Code

```
app.post('/apicall', functionname('file'), onfileupload);
```

The File Upload Function

```
var functionname= multer({ storage: fnupload});

var fnupload= multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {

    mkdirp(__dirname + directoryname, function (err) {
      if (err) console.error(err)
        cb(null, __dirname + directoryname);
    });
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {

  var f =  Date.now()+'_'+file.originalname;
    cb(null,Date.now() + f)
   picname = f;
  } 
})
```

in `fnupload` first section i.e. destination you can set the directory where you want your photo to be stored. `directoryname` used there is actually a variable name that you can send back a response to the front end.
`picname` used in second part of the function is a variable as well that will be your photo's name that is uploaded there.

```
function onfileupload(req, res){
res.json({status : 200, photoname : picname, directoryaddress : directoryname});
}
```

Now you will get a response on your frontend and if you will be using the ngfileupload module the response will be in `response.data`.

Go through Multer documentation on official github to learn more about things I have used in the implementation. If needed. 
Cheers!

Comment: I would greatly appreciate if you provide an example of the code for your first solution. All i need is to upload the the file to the web server with its name and respective directory address.  There will be a secondary process that will read the flat file and update the database appropriately

Comment: Done @AnthonyS. I hope this will help you.

Comment: Sorry was pulled to work on emergency fix within another application.  I will try it as soon as i complete the emergency

Comment: Please see my answer for issue

Comment: Why did you post this as an answer, you could have made a pastebin link. Anyway coming to the problem. Check your angular code and check the jsfiddle I have given for reference. When you are calling the function name you are not actually sending the file as parameter, do that and it will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I attempted to implement the suggestion but run into a major roadblock.

I update my testarea.html with the following code

```
<input type="file" name="fileUpload" value="fileUpload" placeholder="none" file-model="myFile" />
<br>
<br>
<button ng-click='uploadFile()'>Upload</button>"
```

I began setting up my teatarea.router.js as follows

```
'use strict';

angular
.module('testApp')
.config(function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('app.testarea', {
            url: '/testarea',
            views: {
                '': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/components/testarea/testarea.html',
                    controller: 'TestareaCtrl',
                    resolve: {
                        deps: ['$ocLazyLoad',
                            function($ocLazyLoad) {
                                return $ocLazyLoad.load(['app/components/testarea/testarea.controller.js',
                                                         'app/components/testarea/testarea.service.js',
                                                         'ngFileUpload']);
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        });
});
```

I set up my testarea.controller.js as follows

'use strict';

```
angular
.module('testApp')

.controller('TestareaCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', 'Upload',
    function($scope, $timeout, Upload)
  {
        $scope.message = 'Hello';

   $scope.uploadFiles = function(file, errFiles)
   {
    $scope.f = file;
    $scope.errFile = errFiles && errFiles[0];
    if (file)
    {
     file.upload = Upload.upload(
                   {
                    url: 'https://angular-file-upload-cors-srv.appspot.com/upload',
                    data: {file: file}
                   });

        file.upload
           .then(function (response)
            {
             $timeout(function ()
             {
              file.result = response.data;
             });
            }, 
            function (response)
            {
             if (response.status > 0)
                $scope.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
            },
            function (evt)
            {
             file.progress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
            });
    }   
   }
    }]);
```

When I save my code and switch to my browser (Google Chrome) I receive the following message:

ngFileUpload:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

In addition, I receive the following message

angular.js:11607 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: UploadProvider <- Upload <- TestareaCtrl

I verified my node_modules and validate i have ng-file-upload folder

I search for the error but with AngularJS, nodeJS, expressjs, couchbase, etc, I honestly do not know where to start.  Especially, since I only started coding with these technologies recently.  I have many year of experience coding in other languages/technology including SQL databases.  I understand the concepts of what needs to be coded but with these technologies, I do not understand the how to code.

TIA